# Find friend# of all users: How to implement with Hadoop Mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Say I have a input as follows:

```
(1,2)(2,1)(1,3)(3,2)(2,4)(4,1)
```

Ouput is expected as follows:

```
(1,(2,3,4)) -> (1,3) //second index is total friend #
(2,(1,3,4)) -> (2,3)
(3,(1,2))   -> (3,2)
(4,(1,2))   -> (4,2)
```

I know how to do this with hashset in java. But don't know how this work with mapreduce model. Can any one throw any ideas or sample code on this problem? I will appreciate this.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Here is my naive solution: 1 mapper, two reducer. 
The **mapper** will organize input(1,2),(2,1),(1,3);

Organize output as

*(1,hashset<2>),(2,hashSet<1>),(1,hashset<2>),(2,hashset<1>),(1,hashset<3>),(3,hashset<1>).***

**Reducer1**:

take mapper's output as input and output as:

*(1,hashset<2,3>), (3,hashset<1>)and (2,hashset<1>)***

**Reducer2**:

take reducer1's output as input and output as:

*(1,2),(3,1) and (2,1)***

This is only my naive solution. I'm not sure if this can be done by hadoop's code.

Comment: I've already updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being helped by so many excellent engineers, I finally tried out the solution.

Only one Mapper and one Reducer. No combiner here.

input of Mapper:

```
1,2
2,1
1,3
3,1
3,2
3,4
5,1
```

Output of Mapper:

```
1,2
2,1
1,2
2,1
1,3
3,1
1,3
3,1
4,3
3,4
1,5
5,1
```

Output Of Reducer:

```
1   3
2   2
3   3
4   1
5   1
```

The first col is user, the second is friend#.

On the reducer stage, I add hashSet to assistant analysis. 
Thanks @Artem Tsikiridis @Ashish
Your answer gave me a nice clue.

**Edited:**

### Added Code:

//mapper

```
public static class TokenizerMapper extends
        Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text word1 = new Text();
    private Text word2 = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        if(itr.hasMoreElements()){
         word1.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase());

        }
        if(itr.hasMoreElements()){
            word2.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase());

        }
        context.write(word1, word2);
        context.write(word2, word1);
```

//
        }
    }

//reducer

```
public static class IntSumReducer extends
        Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HashSet<Text> set = new HashSet<Text>();
          int sum = 0;
          for (Text val : values) {
                if(!set.contains(val)){
                    set.add(val);
                    sum++;
                }
          }   

          result.set(sum);
          context.write(key, result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there should be an easy way to solve this problem.

```
Mapper Input: (1,2)(2,1)(1,3)(3,2)(2,4)(4,1)
```

Just emit two records for each pair like this:

```
Mapper Output/ Reducer Input:

Key => Value
1 => 2
2 => 1
2 => 1
1 => 2
1 => 3
3 => 1
3 => 2
2 => 3
2 => 4
4 => 2
4 => 1
1 => 1
```

At reducer side, you'll get 4 different groups like this:

```
Reducer Output:

Key => Values
1 => [2,3,4]
2 => [1,3,4]
3 => [1,2]
4 => [1,2]
```

Now, you are good to format your result as you want. :)
Let me know if anybody can see any issue in this approach

Comment: But aren't the values supposed to be passed sorted to the reducers?

Comment: Requirement is to find all the friends so sorting won't be required. If required then we can sort these values in reducer itself. And still have issue of memory then Secondary sort option can be applied.

Comment: You are right. It seems that I misunderstood the actual problem, so my answer with the secondary sort is pretty much obsolete :( Sorry. I will edit my post.

Comment: @Ashish Can you elaborate how the reducer output come out? In my point of view, it's supposed to be 1 -> [2,2,3,1], which means the value may be duplicated.

Comment: @Ashish I've tried out. I used a hash to process the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## 1) Intro / Problem

Before going ahead with the job driver, it is important to understand that in a simple-minded approach, the values of the reducers should be **sorted** in an ascending order. The first thought is to pass the value list unsorted and do some sorting in the reducer per key. This has two disadvantages:

1) It is most probably **not efficient** for large Value Lists

and

2) How will the framework know if (1,4) is equal to (4,1) if these pairs are processed in different parts of the cluster?

## 2) Solution in theory

The way to do it in Hadoop is to "mock" the framework in a way by creating a **synthetic key**.

So our map function instead of the "conceptually more appropriate" (if I may say that)

`map(k1, v1) -> list(k2, v2)`

is the following:

`map(k1, v1) -> list(ksynthetic, null)`

As you notice we discard the usage of values (the reducer still gets a list of `null` values but we don't really care about them). What happens here is that these values are actually **included** in `ksynthetic`. Here is an example for the problem in question:

`` `map(1, 2) -> list([1,2], null) ``

However, some more operations need to be done so that the keys are grouped and partitioned appropriately and we achieve the correct result in the reducer.

## 3) Hadoop Implementation

We will implement a class called `FFGroupKeyComparator` and a class `FindFriendPartitioner`.

Here is our `FFGroupKeyComparator`:

```
public static class FFGroupComparator extends WritableComparator
{
    protected FFGroupComparator() 
    {
        super(Text.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2)
    {

        Text t1 = (Text) w1;
        Text t2 = (Text) w2;
        String[] t1Items = t1.toString().split(",");
        String[] t2Items = t2.toString().split(",");
        String t1Base = t1Items[0];
        String t2Base = t2Items[0];
        int comp = t1Base.compareTo(t2Base); // We compare using "real" key part of our synthetic key

        return comp;

    }
}
```

This class will act as our Grouping Comparator class. It controls which keys are grouped together for a single call to `Reducer.reduce(Object, Iterable, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context)` This is very important as it ensures that each reducer gets the appropriate synthetic keys ( judging by the real key).

Due to the fact that Hadoop runs in a cluster with many nodes it is important to ensure that there as many reduce tasks as partitions. Their number should be the same as of the **real keys** (not synthetic). So, usually we do this with hash values. In our case, what we need to do is compute the partition that a synthetic key belongs based on the hash value of the real key (before the comma). So our `FindFriendPartitioner` is as follows:

```
public static class FindFriendPartitioner extends Partitioner  implements Configurable
{
    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, Text NullWritable, int numPartitions) 
    {

        String[] keyItems = key.toString().split(",");
        String keyBase = keyItems[0];
        int part  = keyBase.hashCode() % numPartitions;
        return part;
    }
```

So now we are all set to write the actual job and solve our problem.

I am assuming your input file looks like this:

```
1,2
2,1
1,3
3,2
2,4
4,1
```

We will use the `TextInputFormat`.

Here's the code for the job driver using Hadoop 1.0.4:

```
public class FindFriendTwo
{       
    public static class FindFriendMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, NullWritable> {

public void map(Object, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{       
        context.write(value, new NullWritable() );

        String tempStrings[] = value.toString().split(","); 

        Text value2 = new Text(tempStrings[1] + "," + tempStrings[0]); //reverse relationship

        context.write(value2, new NullWritable());

}
```

}

Notice that we also passed the reverse relationships in the `map` function.

For example if the input string is (1,4) we must not forget (4,1).

```
public static class FindFriendReducer extends Reducer<Text, NullWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> { 

    private Set<String> friendsSet;
    public void setup(Context context)
    {
        friendSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    }

    public void reduce(Text syntheticKey, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String tempKeys[] = syntheticKey.toString().split(",");
        friendsSet.add(tempKeys[1]);

        if( friendsList.size() == 2 )
        {
            IntWritable key = Integer.parseInt(tempKeys[0]);
            IntWritable value = Integer.parseInt(tempKeys[1]);                
            write(key, value);
        }



   }

}
```

Finally, we must remember to include the following in our Main Class, so that the framework uses our classes.

```
jobConf.setGroupingComparatorClass(FFGroupComparator.class);
jobConf.setPartitionerClass(FindFriendPartitioner.class);
```

Comment: Superb and detailed explanation. I will try my solution first to see if my way is working. Will discuss with you once I test my code tomo. I do appreciate your attitude on Big Data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChrisSu You're very welcome! I am trying to learn too :) . Ok. Please tell me if something is missing so I can update the answer.

Comment: (It seems that I misunderstood the problem and I apologise for that. But if for some reason you need sorted values check my post about secondary sort :))

Comment: Yea~ I will. Thanks a lot. I'm still trying my solution. :)

Comment: @ChrisSu any simple final solution? because this all looks very complex. if the problem is simple and solution is very complex then must be something wrong we are doing...

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem as follows.

- Make sure we have all the relations and have them exactly once each.
- Simply count the

Notes on my aproach:

- My notation for key value pairs is : K -> V
- Both key and value are a almost always a datastructure (not just a string or int)
- I *never* use the key for data. The key is ONLY there to control the flow from mappers towards the right reducer. In all other places I do not look at the key at all. The framework does require a key everywhere. With '()' I mean to say that there is a key that I ignore completely.
- The key about my aproach is that it never needs 'all friends' in memory at the same moment (so it works also in the really big situations).

We start with a lot of

```
(x,y)
```

and we know that we do not have all relationships in the dataset.

Mapper: Create all relations

```
Input:  ()    -> (x,y)
Output: (x,y) -> (x,y)
        (y,x) -> (y,x)
```

Reducer: Remove duplicates (simply only output the first one from the iterator)

```
Input:  (x,y) -> [(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),.... ]
Output: ()    -> (x,y)
```

Mapper: "Wordcount"

```
Input:  ()  -> (x,y)
Output: (x) -> (x,1)
```

Reducer: Count them

```
Input:  (x) -> [(x,1),(x,1),(x,1),(x,1),.... ]
Output: ()  -> (x,N)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution provides a better view of removing duplicates.